# Getting Invalid sender error while creating contract from remix

Tags: solidity, go-ethereum, remix

I am getting Invalid sender error while creating contact in private network. Though i have kept chainId and networkId are same.

Comment: Do you have the exact error message? Also make sure the sender account has enough balance to deploy the contract.

Comment: I have checked account balance and it is 0. will it be the primary reason for this error?

Comment: If that is the reason behind this error then how can i able to update account with some balance?

Comment: After starting miner now i have 19746 ether in my account , but still getting same error.

Comment: Make sure you are connecting to your private network, and unlock your account.

Comment: @Ismael I did all these things but still getting same error.Even i try to deploy very simple contract i got this error.creation of test errored: Gas required exceeds limit: 3000000.  An important gas estimation might also be the sign of a problem in the contract code. Please check loops and be sure you did not sent value to a non payable function (that's also the reason of strong gas estimation).

Comment: Remix has a "Gas Limit" in the "Run" section where you can increase the defaul 3M. The current limit is about 8M in mainnet, if you increase that beyond the 8M and still fails then either your contract is too big or the constructor has a bug. I'd advice first try with a simple contract, so you can discard it being too big.

Comment: @Ismael thanks, This issue has been resolved by changing the chainId 0 to  10 in genesis block.

Answer (score 0):

Check the private Network ,Private Network Create Command 
run `geth` makedir and `cmd` open and this command run :

```
$ geth --networkid 13 --port 30303 --datadir "E:\bolckchain\chaindata" console
```

[image]
**Then check Network :**

```
> admin
```

[image]

same Network 
then sender contact

Try it

Thank You!

Answer (score 0):

I just tested with latest chrome extension and it works like a charm.
Update your Chrome extension.
Version: 4.1.2
Updated: 28 February 2018